# Spring CrudRepository not saving more than 32,000 characters

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to save an entity using Springs crud repository (repo.save(Entity)) to my sql db - for some reason though when the entity is saved, the entity's variables/payloads are cut off at 32,000 characters in the db. Is there a limit that is causing this? (The column in my SQL db is type LONGTEXT - max of ~4million characters).

Comment: What's your database and what's the exact column definition?

Comment: Which Http method are you using to save through the UI?

Comment: SQL and column type LONGTEXT

Comment: SQL is a language name, not a database name

Comment: The database is mySql :)

Comment: If you are saving it through UI using GET method, It holds a size limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with annotating the column with @Lob, and specifying as columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT"